# jQuery-UI AutoComplete not working for dynamic fields

Tags: jquery, html, json, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

AutoComplete works correctly for the static field, but it doesn't work for dynamic fields.

I've tried `.live()` method for I could not get it to work correctly.

Here is my HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr class="selectmatprimas">
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="selectmatprima" />
            <input type="text" name="matprimas[]" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clone" style="display:none;">
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="selectmatprima" />
            <input type="text" name="matprimas[]" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="addmore" id="addmore" />
```

​
Here is my JS:

```
var src = [
    {
        "label": "Mat\u00e9ria Prima 1",
        "value": "1"
    },
    {
        "label": "Mat\u00e9ria Prima 2",
        "value": "2"
    }
];

$("input.selectmatprima").autocomplete({
    source: src,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.value = ui.item.label;
        $(this).next().val(ui.item.value);
    },
    focus: function (event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.value = ui.item.label;
        $(this).next().val(ui.item.value);
    }
});

$("input#addmore").click(function(){
    var a = $('tr.clone').html();
    var b = $('tr.selectmatprimas:last');
    b.after("<tr class='selectmatprimas'>"+a+"</tr>");
});
```

[Online DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pK78z/)

As you can see, when I click the addmore button, the autocomplete doesn't work on the new fields...

Comment: the best way I've found to do such a thing would be to use `.on` (since `.live` is deprecated) to handle either `click` or `focus` events for the dynamically loaded input, then setup autocomplete when that event fires

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've only scratched the surface with your code but here's a working [version](http://jsfiddle.net/pK78z/2/)

The key is jQuery's `on()` function which you can read about [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Thanks, it works! But wouldn't it better be focus instead of keyup?

Comment: Was just doing that as you commented. Check the link again. It'll work with both.

Comment: I know its been a while but this totally helped me stop scratching my head for 2 days. Thanks so much